# Associative array is not working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative

The code below is not working Indexed arrays work fine,
    
    
    Look Out World

```
<?php
//sorting an Associative array

$age=array("peter"=>"19", "john"=>"18, "alex"=>"17");
asort($age);    


//looping an associative array

foreach($age as $x=>$x_value)
{
    echo "Name = " .$x. "age = " .$x_value. "<br>";
 } 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an syntax error , you havent closed and double quotes

```
$age=array("peter"=>"19", "john"=>"18", "alex"=>"17");
asort($age);
```

More over age can be given as an integar

```
$age=array("peter"=>19, "john"=>18, "alex"=>17);
asort($age);
```